# Why does Debug.Writeline output some variables to the left of my text?

Tags: c#

I have the following code and I want to know why the output from the line 'Asset Name' sticks the variable to the left of my text instead of the right? Can anyone help?

This:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(" ------------ LoadContent ------------");
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("LoadContent: Asset Name : {0}", theAsset);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("LoadContent: Sprite X Offset : {0}", thisSpriteXCentreOffset);
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("LoadContent: Sprite Y Offset : {0}", thisSpriteYCentreOffset);
```

Outputs this (Bold line being the unexpected one):

> ------------ LoadContent ------------
>
> **SpaceShip: LoadContent: Asset Name : {0}**
>
> LoadContent: Sprite X Offset : 64
>
> LoadContent: Sprite Y Offset : 32

Comment: Could you try: `Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("LoadContent: Asset Name : {0}". theAsset));`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is that `theAsset` is a `string`, and you're therefore invoking [`Debug.WriteLine(string, string)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/1w33ay0x(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of [`Debug.WriteLine(string, object[])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190153(v=vs.110).aspx).  The second argument in this case is interpreted as a "category" and prepended to the output.

You might try casting it to an `object` to invoke the correct overload:

```
Debug.WriteLine("LoadContent: Asset Name : {0}", (object)theAsset);
```

Comment: theAsset is a string containing a name of a picture being used as part of the LoadContent method in XNA  as per  "thisSprite = theContentManager.Load<Texture2D>(theAsset);".  Being fairly new at this, I'm guessing that you may be correct.

Comment: Tried the (object) and it did the trick. Reading my comment above, 'theAsset' is indeed a string and therefore would be invoking that method instead. Thanks

Comment: `Debug.Print` is probably slightly easier to use. No tricky overloads that you need to remember to deal with.