# debug writeline has strange output

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, visual-studio-2012

Coding in VS-2012 Express for Web -- VB.Net with this code...

```
Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(vbTab + ".prpUID_REPORT      = [{0}]", .prpUID_REPORT)
Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(vbTab + ".prpRV_HeaderDSName = [{0}]", .prpRV_HeaderDSName)
Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(vbTab + ".prpRV_HeaderDSId   = [{0}]", .prpRV_HeaderDSId)
Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(vbTab + ".prpRV_ReportDSName = [{0}]", .prpRV_ReportDSName)
Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(vbTab + ".prpRV_ReportDSId   = [{0}]", .prpRV_ReportDSId)
Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(vbTab + ".prpRV_ReportPath   = [{0}]", .prpRV_ReportPath)
```

Results in this in the Immediate-window:

```
   .prpUID_REPORT      = [22]
   dsetCustHeader:  .prpRV_HeaderDSName = [{0}]
   SDS_RptHeader:   .prpRV_HeaderDSId   = [{0}]
   dsetReportContentAll:    .prpRV_ReportDSName = [{0}]
   SDS_RptData:     .prpRV_ReportDSId   = [{0}]
   ssrsFleetCostSummary_FLA.rdlc:   .prpRV_ReportPath   = [{0}]
```

Notice that the first debug-line shows the text correctly .prpUID_Report = [22].  However, the next debug-lines show the "value" followed by part of the source code line.  It appears that the substitution into {0} is faulty.

Any clues as to what may be causing this?  I think the debug-source code is syntactically correct, since the first line (= [22]) works as expected but the other lines do not.
Your comments are welcome.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
  Debug.WriteLine(string,string) method call is different from 
  Debug.WriteLine(string,object[])
```

which may be why the first WriteLine statement is working while the rest isnt as the second parameter is possibly a string.

Please check the [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.debug.writeline(v=vs.110).aspx) here

Comment: Also please check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25964139/why-does-debug-writeline-output-some-variables-to-the-left-of-my-text for similar question.

Comment: Thank you for the correct answer.  I found this in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25964139/why-does-debug-writeline-output-some-variables-to-the-left-of-my-text .

Comment: Thank you for the correct answer.  I found this in [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22819117/why-does-debug-writeline-incorrectly-format-strings)  and am using Debug.Print.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using an explicit `String.Format()` call to see if that makes any difference?

```
Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} .prpUID_REPORT = [{1}]",vbTab, .prpUID_REPORT))
Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(String.Format("{0} .prpRV_HeaderDSName = [{1}]",vbTab, .prpRV_HeaderDSName))
` Other code omitted for brevity `
```

It may simply be an issue of the improper method call of the `Debug.WriteLine()` method (i.e. expecting an array or an object and just receiving a string, which is triggering the wrong functionality).